# Issue ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16 on win server 2012R2 .NET

Tags: .net, imagemagick, tiff, windows-server-2012-r2

After downloading ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16 from the official site of ImageMagick, i receive this error when i try to convert a file .tiff to .pdf using this command:

```
convert -resample 200X200 dir.tif dir.pdf
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qolg.png)

and when i try to run using .NET program, this command can't create a file.pdf

```
        ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pinfo.FileName = converterPath;
        pinfo.Arguments = "convert -resample 200X200" + dirTif+ dirPdf;


        Process proc = null;
        try
        {
            proc = Process.Start(pinfo);
            proc.WaitForExit(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

         serviceLogger.WriteMessage("PROCESS EXCEPTION", ex.Message + " | " + ex.StackTrace + " | " +ex.Source );
        }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore them like this:

```
convert image.tif -define tiff:ignore-tags=TAG1,TAG2,TAG3 ...
```

If you want to check what you are ignoring first, look [here](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/search.html?q=5112&Submit=Find%20Tags) to search for TIFF tags.

Comment: sorry, my main problem is that this command can't create a pdf file in a specific directory using .NET

Comment: Huh? That is not what your error messages suggest. Can you show the error messages related to your actual issue please? I presume you have installed `ghostscript` as you can't do anything with PDFs without that?

Comment: in .net the code don't return me any errors,don't create a file pdf

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick from source or from binary? If from source, you  will need to install all the needed delegates that incluce Ghostscript for PDF and libtiff for tiff. All your messages are warnings and not errors. So you can get rid of warnings about unknown tags using -quiet right after convert. Also you should read your input image before applying any operators such as -resample. Sorry, I cannot comment about .NET as I only use the command line. Did you command line create the output PDF? Actually IM creates the PDF without Ghostscript. It only uses Ghostscript to read PDFs.

Comment: thak you for the reply, using command line it generate a file .pdf if it return a warning, while using a code in .NET it not return any errors and not create a file.
However i install 'IM' using source, but within directory of modules/coders seems that i have necessary lib.

Comment: Your code is not actually using the `.Net` interface, rather it is executing an external command-line process. I suspect the issue is probably that the PATH is set differently when you start the `convert` process from within your code from when you type commands into the Terminal/Command-prompt. Check your PATH in Terminal/Command-prompt and make sure it is similar when start the external process in your code.

Comment: the command that i run in command-prompt is the same that i run in .NET code, same directories :(

Comment: Yes, but but it runs in a **different environment**! Your PATH and environment variables are different in your command-prompt from when run from your code. I think the DOS command that tells you your environment is maybe `SET`. Try running that in Command-prompt, then try running it as a process like you are currently running `convert` from your code.

Comment: the path is the same, i think that i must install 'GS', how it influence on this process? thanks @MarkSetchell

Comment: it is needed or not? i don't understand

Comment: ImageMagick is over half a million lines of code that I didn't write. I cannot tell you for absolute certain what it will do in any given situation. If it can generate a PDF file without installing `ghostscript` when run from the command line, then I imagine it should be able to do so when called as a sub-process. I thought it needed `ghostscript` for both reading and writing PDF files, but Fred (@fnw42) has FAR more experience and knowledge than I do and he thinks it is only needed for reading PDFs and that seems to be borne out by your experience...

Comment: ...(continued). All I can say is that there is clearly something wrong with your setup and I am trying to help you find it. Some ideas may not work, there are no guarantees, I am just sharing some knowledge and experience I have accumulated over the years.

Comment: Have you got spaces either side of `dirTif` and `dirPdf` in your command? Can you print the command before you run it?

Comment: i printed a command and it is right, my doubt is 
The directory from where I call the command,it could give me any problems?
I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: You could change your command to `cd \some\where && convert something -resize ...` See here https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: i tried it, but nothing to do :( it don't work, i think that there are any problems whit version of ImageMagick on Windows server 2012 R2